# How to get the user name of the user who uninstalled an application on windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, events, logging, uninstallation

I am trying to parse windows event logs to list every software that has been uninstalled on a device and by who.

Here is what I came up with until now:

- match on events 1040 (applciation uninstall):

---

```
PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command "Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{logname=’application’; id=1040; StartTime=(get-date).AddDays(-1)} | select timecreated, level, id, message, ProviderName, User | Export-Csv -Append C:\BCM\eventerr.csv -notype"
```

- get the "User" given in the event:

---

```
Get-WinEvent -MaxEvents 10 | foreach {
      $sid = $_.userid;
      if($sid -eq $null) { return; }
      $objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($sid);
      $objUser = $objSID.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]);
      Write-Host $objUser.Value;
    }
```

But it begins by outputing an error:

> Error: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.. At line:1
>   char:1 + Get-WinEvent -MaxEvents 10 | foreach { +
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:)
>   [Get-WinEvent], Exception + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   LogInfoUnavailable,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWinEvent‌​Command

Then it outputs a list of 2 users...

**EDIT: the following is useless since I since realized that the second command line doesn't (always?) output a proper result...**

I tried to combine these like this:

```
PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command "Get-WinEvent -MaxEvents 10 -FilterHashTable @{logname=’application’; id=1040; StartTime=(get-date).AddDays(-1)} | select timecreated, level, id, message, ProviderName, User | foreach {$sid = $_.userid; if($sid -eq $null) { return; } $objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($sid); $objUser = $objSID.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]); Write-Host $objUser.Value;}| Export-Csv -Append C:\BCM\eventerr.csv -notype"
```

But I get this error in the powershell window:

> At line:1 char:325
>   + ... rityIdentifier(); AD\user = S-1-5-21-935981524-3360503449-101602611-2988 ...
>   +                    ~ An expression was expected after '('.
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedExpression

Can someone help me fix that please?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: One thing wrong is missing a semicolon after `if($sid -eq $null) { return; }`,

Comment: Did you delete your comment sodawillow? I'm not much used to powershell, why would it be easier to debug if it was in a file?

Comment: Actually I realized that the second command line is only partially working:

Get-WinEvent : Could not retrieve information about the Security log. Error: Attempted to perform an unauthorized
operation..
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-WinEvent -MaxEvents 10 | foreach {
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WinEvent], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : LogInfoUnavailable,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWinEventCommand

Then it outputs a list of 2 users...

Comment: I edited the original post (about 10 times... ><) to reflect this.

Comment: I tried to add a semicolon BenH, without more success...

Comment: I see one glaring issue with the second command. Your `Select` command doesn't pass the property `UserID` which the `ForEach` loop relies on. As for the first one, are you executing that under Administrator context?

Comment: Sorry, I had not seen your comment: this was ran using my account which is an administrator account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your two functions combined:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{logname='application'; id=1040; StartTime=(get-date).AddDays(-10)} | ? {$_.userid} | % {
    $objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier ($_.userid)
    $objUser = $objSID.Translate( [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
    [pscustomobject]@{
        User = $objUser.Value
        timecreated = $_.timecreated
        level = $_.level
        id = $_.id
        message = $_.message
        ProviderName = $_.ProviderName
    }
} | Export-Csv -Append C:\BCM\eventerr.csv -notype
```

And here it is as an extremely long oneliner:

```
PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command "Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{logname='application'; id=1040; StartTime=(get-date).AddDays(-10)} | ? {$_.userid} | % {$objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier ($_.userid); $objUser = $objSID.Translate( [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]);[pscustomobject]@{User = $objUser.Value;timecreated = $_.timecreated;level = $_.level;id = $_.id;message = $_.message;ProviderName = $_.ProviderName}} | Export-Csv -Append C:\BCM\eventerr.csv -notype"
```

Edit: Added `Where-Object` Filter to remove entries which the logs does not have a userid resolving the `A constructor was not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier.` error message.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work on my end. If I use your first command it outputs this:

New-Object : A constructor was not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier.
At line:2 char:15
+ ...   $objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier ( ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotFindAppropriateCtor,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Comment: Where the second one outputs this:

= : The term '=' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:176
+ ... ct System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier (.userid);  = .Transl ...
+                                                                 ~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (=:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: @druid `System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier` has been around since .Net 2.0. What OS and version of PowerShell are you running this on?

Comment: I made test on a windows 10 computer at the beginning but these logs are extracted from a windows 7 device... I'll try again on a windows 10, just in case. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Windows 7 SP1 comes with .Net 3.5.1 if I remember right, so I don't know why you are getting that error unless you disabled the .Net framework "Windows feature"

Comment: Ok, thanks. i'll try to work on this later if I get time to.